# Java AES decryption - can't decrypt string

Tags: java, string, encryption, aes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java AES Encrypt Entire String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781348/java-aes-encrypt-entire-string)

I've run into a small problem.  For some reason, I can't decrypt some strings using the same method that I encrypt them.  For example, I'm using this code for decrypting:

```
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    String result = new String(cipher.doFinal(message));

    System.out.println("Decrypted:" + result);
```

Anyway, when the salt is "1231231231231231" and the message that im trying to decrypt is "read". I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

But the encryptor (which works the same way) says the encrypted value is

```
I¡?Þd↨Ú#à, 7êLO*
```

How can I fix this or avoid the user from inputting such strings? Thansk

Comment: *"please ignore the messiness"*  No problem, I'll just ignore your post.

Comment: That has to go down as the 'dummy spit of the week'.  I recommend reading [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), with particular reference to [On Not Reacting Like A Loser](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#not_losing).  Good luck!

Comment: "...and the message to be encrypted is 'read'": aren't you trying to decrypt? You need to pass in the output of an encrypt operation with the same padding to the above function.

Comment: sorry, thats what i ment. After encrypting "read" the output is "I¡?Þd↨Ú#à, 7êLO*" but when I try to decrypt that with the same  key I get the error I posted. I edited the initial post.

Comment: And do you also encrypt with PKCS#5 padding? In any case, you can decrypt with no padding, and look at the decrypted data to see why JCE thinks the padding is not PKCS#5.

Comment: ooh i think i figured out my problem, now to why does it happen. basically my encryptor converts the encrypted text into a string and then converts that back into a byte which it sends to the decryptor. somewhere along the way the padding is lost i guess. now how to fix this :S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: don't store it in a string.

Your call to `Cipher.doFinal` should be stored in a `byte` array (`byte[]`), and your input to the decryption should likewise be a `byte` array.  If you're taking a `String` input, use `.getBytes()`; when you're creating the `String` for an output, use `new String(myArray)`

Comment: yah i know, this is how my program works: 
string gets encrypted (output is byte).
output is converted to string and stored in a seperate text file.
it's then read from the text file and converted back to byte.
decryptor decrypts the byte.

but apperantly 
  `byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
  String stringResult = new String(result);
stringResult.getBytes()` does not reverse the process entirely