# Gradle script for AES encryption

Tags: android, encryption, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For an Android app I want to obfuscate/encrypt the server public key when building with gradle.

Right now I'm obfuscating using Base64 but I need AES as an extra

```
task encryptKeys {
    doFirst {

        //Encrypt the server key


        // Load key
        byte[] key = new File('project/keys/server.crt.der').bytes

        // Encode key twice
        String encoded = key.encodeBase64().toString();
        encoded = encoded.bytes.encodeBase64().toString();

        //TODO AES ENCRYPTION HERE

        // Save key
        new File('project/src/main/assets/server.crt.der').bytes = encoded.getBytes()
```

Later at runtime when using this key i would decrypt it like this

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText) throws Exception{
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
      SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
      return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),"UTF-8");
}
```

What would be the correct way to encrypt my key with AES in gradle script? Google couldn't help me out. Is this something that's possible at all or would I need to find another solution?

Comment: Are you using the key `project/keys/server.crt.der` to encrypt itself? when you are trying to decrypt this resultant file (in your latter java block), how are you getting `encryptionKey`? You can't use the result of the first AES encryption as that needs the key to unlock itself, unless you store the key with the application, at which point it makes it pointless storing the obfuscated/encrypted version of itself. I'm a little unsure of how you expect to only store an encrypted file and expect it to be able to decrypt itself.

Comment: I will not use this key to encrypt itself. This key will be used to sign messages sent to the server. This key will be encrypted by another key hidden in my code to make it harder for attackers to figure out the key when they decompile this app

Comment: @MrJM How did you achieve it? Could you please share?

Comment: It was a long time ago and I don't have access to the code anymore. I think the accepted answer below is the approach I followed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a similar [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781348/java-aes-encrypt-entire-string) for encrypting a string with AES in java.

I've adopted this into a gradle script below.

It will encrypt the `SERVERKEY` string (in your version load this from external source) with the key `KEY`. I don't have BouncyCastle installed, so I used SunJCE, but I left it as a parameter so you can change it easily.

The output in this simple case is the file "obf.enc". The `decIt` task will also decrypt and print out to show it's worked symmetrically.

Your hardest part is obviously the fact your `KEY` for encrypting is embedded in your application (hence my question in the comments), so this is just security through obscurity, but if that's good enough for the application, so be it.

```
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import javax.crypto.Cipher

ext {
    KEY = "mysecretkey".padRight(16).getBytes("UTF-8")
    SERVERKEY = "serverkey"
    IV = "1234".padRight(16).getBytes("UTF-8")
    PROVIDER = "SunJCE"
}

task encIt << {
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES")
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", PROVIDER)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV))
    def encBytes = cipher.doFinal(SERVERKEY.bytes)
    def out = file('obf.enc')
    out.delete()
    out << encBytes
}

task decIt << {
    def cipherText = file('obf.enc').bytes
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", PROVIDER)
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV))
    println new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8")
}
```